# Thread wait using WaitHandles in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, waithandle

Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a login class. Once the user is authenticated, some post login operations are done in a thread. And the user gets to home page.

Now from home page I go to a different functionality, say class FindProduct. I need to check if post login operations in the login thread are completed. Only if post login operation is completed I allow to enter the functionality.

Do I have to put wait handles on PerformLoginAsyncThread as well as OnClickFindProduct?

```
Class Login
{
   public bool Login(Userinfo)
   {
      // do tasks like authenticate
      if(authenticationValid)
         {
          PerformLoginAsyncThread(UserInfo)
          //continue to homepage
         }
   }   

}

Class HomePage
{
   public void OnClickFindProduct
   {
     if(finishedPostLoginThread)
        // proceed to Find Product page
     else
         {
           //If taking more than 8 seconds, throw message and exit app
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for us to answer this.

Comment: You can do the Post login operation as a `Async-Await` call, when Home page loads and enable the `FindProduct` only when the Post login call returns. Provide more details regarding your system, I am assuming its ASP.Net MVC capable of making `Async` calls, using `WaitHandles` in this case will lead to deadlock.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj the problem is I'm using C# 2.0. There are a lot of legacy systems which require 2.0, so I have no choice to upgrade. I doubt if it has async. 
The problem is also that I'm new to threading concept. :|

Comment: C# 2.0, doesn't have `Async-Await`, provide more system / project details to understand your requirements better, like web application (Asp.net) etc

Comment: use a global static ManualResetEvent, when complete the login set a signal. now you can use handler.Wait(8000) == false in FindProduct method, another solution is use a delegate/callback queue, but it is complicate

Comment: Just don't do this hard way.  There is no point in starting the thread until after the login succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general idea how to use `EventWaitHandle`s. You need to `Reset` it before doing the work, and `Set` it when you are done.

In the example below I have made the `ResetEvent` property static, but I suggest you pass the instance somehow instead, I just could not do it without more details about your architecture.

```
class Login
{
     private Thread performThread;
     public static ManualResetEvent ResetEvent { get; set; }
     public bool Login(Userinfo)
     {
        // do tasks like authenticate
        if(authenticationValid)
        {
            PerformLoginAsyncThread(UserInfo);
            //continue to homepage
        }
    }   

    private void PerformLoginAsyncThread(UserInfo)
    {
        ResetEvent.Reset();
        performThread = new Thread(() => 
        {
            //do stuff
            ResetEvent.Set();
        });
        performThread.Start();
    }
}

class HomePage
{
    public void OnClickFindProduct
    {
        bool finishedPostLoginThread = Login.ResetEvent.WaitOne(8000);
        if(finishedPostLoginThread)
        {
            // proceed to Find Product page
        }
        else
        {
            //If taking more than 8 seconds, throw message and exit app
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to complicate your logic with await or raising an event the simplest solution would be inside the PerformLoginAsyncThread function just set a **session variable** to true on complete and in your OnClickFindProduct check for the session variable.